# Capture network logs using wendriverio

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

Requirement : I want to capture the payload for the POST call that goes for analaytics on every action, page load etc in my automation framework. I am using webdriverio.

The below code is printing empty response []. What am I doing wrong?

```
describe('Test Describe ', () => {

it('Perform initial setup', async () => {

    await browser.url("https://google.com");
    await browser.pause(30000);
    await browser.setupInterceptor();

    console.log("hello candy");

    let requestLog = await browser.getRequest(
        "POST",
        "<url of the REST api I want to capture>"
    )

    await browser.pause(20000);
    console.log("Network Traffic Capture");
    console.log(requestLog);


})
})
```

What is it I am doing wrong?

Package.json :

```
{
  "name": "my-new-project",
  "type": "module",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@wdio/cli": "^8.10.7",
    "@wdio/junit-reporter": "^8.10.6",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^8.10.7",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^8.10.7",
    "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^8.10.7",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^8.10.6",
    "wdio-html-nice-reporter": "^8.1.0",
    "wdio-intercept-service": "^4.2.2",
    "wdio-selenium-standalone-service": "^0.0.12",
    "wdio-timeline-reporter": "^5.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "wdio": "wdio run ./wdio.conf.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.3.7",
    "chromedriver": "^114.0.1",
    "webdriverio": "^8.10.7"
  }
}
```

UPDATE :

I am able to get logs now with below code butit is fetching all GET calls and not the specific call I have provided

```
describe('Homescreen verification ', () => {

    it('Perform initial setup', async () => {
        
        await browser.url("https://stage.creativecloud.adobe.com/apps/download/creative-cloud");
        await browser.setupInterceptor();

        console.log("hello candy");
        await browser.waitUntil(async () => {
            const requestLog = await browser.getRequest(
                "POST",
                "https://api-endpoint/path/*"
            );
            return requestLog.length > 0;
          });

        let requestLog = await browser.getRequest(
            "POST",
            "https://api-endpoint/path/*"
        )

        console.log("Network Traffic Capture");
        console.log(requestLog);

        //console.log("printing headers");
       // console.log(requestLog[1].body.events[0].data);


    })
})
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated